# R- How to scan the nth variable of every nth row in an input table

Tags: r

I used read.table to input a .dat file. I would like to define a list to contain the 2nd variable, but only for the rows starting at row 7 and every 9th row after that. (So row 7, row 16, row 25......row 10429). Could I set up the scan function or any other function to do this?

For example:

```
  1           0           1
           1   223.190870109536     
           2   236.811795353886     
           3   499.836079072149     
           4  -2.84289605856125     
           5   10.1209420763388     
           6   25.7789822728439     
           7   25.7789822728439     
 0  0.39524E+01  0.15332E+00
           2           1           1
           1  -2.97259433271086     
           2   1.33290127489590     
           3   0.00000000000000     
           4  -13.3039519272810     
           5  -26.8552876791965     
           6   17.9522993970202     
           7   17.9522993970202     
 0  0.14078E+01  0.78420E-01
           2           1           1
           1   12.6408810567997     
           2  -10.0191313878416     
           3  -33.9713889917032     
           4  -22.8799882366969     
           5  -23.4375397262546     
           6   20.0671762933887     
           7   20.0671762933887     
 0  0.14243E+01  0.70976E-01
```

The values repeat in this format. I would like to save a list with every value after a 6.

Comment: Can you show a small example data and expected output based on that.  For selecting rows, may be `?seq` can be used. Perhaps `yourdata[seq(7, 10429, by=9),2]`

Comment: Please see: stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: It is not possible to read every nth row but skipping is possible using the `skip` argument in `read.table`. Look at the documentation for this function: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html

Comment: The number of elements in each row seems to be different.  First row with 3, 2 to 8 with 2, again 3, ..

Comment: Not sure what a .dat file is... never seen that used as a data transfer format. Nor does it seem like the example data could be read in with `read.table` for the reason akrun mentioned -- column counts must be consistent across rows.

Comment: May be `lines <- readLines('file.txt');read.table(text=lines[seq(7, length(lines), by=9)], header=FALSE)[,2]#[1] 25.77898 17.95230 20.06718`

Comment: I used fill=TRUE to read it in.

Comment: It will get NA's as padding.  Have you tried the code above?

Comment: akrun, that line seemed to work in the console output, which listed all of the values after 6s, which is what I wanted. But when it saved it as lines, it saved everything, not just those values I wanted

Comment: You have to create a new object i.e. `v1 <- read.table(text=lines[seq(7, length(lines), by=9)], header=FALSE)[,2]` and then save it.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.

Comment: One more question: It is working fine, but now it is rounding all of the values to the nearest tenths place. Is there a way to avoid this and keep more decimal places to keep the values more precise?

Comment: @AsefIslam I posted an `awk` solution.  Can you try that?  It seems to be not rounding.  The rounding might be a print issue.

Comment: Hmm... Can you please clarify how to use that awk command?

Comment: `awk` works on linux.  I am using linux.  You need to open the terminal, change the directory to the one where your file is present, and then try those codes.

Comment: I am getting this Error: unexpected string constant in "awk 'NR%9==7 {print $2}'"

Comment: Are you using linux?

Comment: No, I am on Windows using RStudio.

Comment: Ok, it may not work on windows. Sorry

Comment: That's fine. Thanks for your readLines solution, that should suffice.

Comment: When I print the saved list as a column as part of a data frame, it is also numbering them from 1 to n. Do you know if there might be a way to get rid of the numbering and have just the values when I add it to the data frame?

Comment: Do you have a solution to my new question?

Comment: I didn't check your new question, but as far as this question is concerned, it is answered

Comment: I meant the latest comment on this question

Comment: I assume you are using the `readLines/read.table` approach as you don't have the linux.   Based on the output I showed, it is a `vector` v1.  I don't understand the numbering you talked about.  If you create a `data.frame`, by default there is row number, which you can't delete

Comment: When I print the list as a column in a data frame, it doesn't just print the values in a single column, like this:

Comment: 25.8       18     20.1               Rather, it also numbers them, creating two columns:   1     25.8      2  18     3  20.1

Comment: Can you try `unname(v1)` assuming that it is the names. or just `as.vector(v1)`

Comment: It's still happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to read the file using `readLines` and then `subset` the rows using `seq`, read with `read.table` and get the 2nd column.

```
 lines <- readLines('file.txt')
 v1 <- read.table(text=lines[seq(7, length(lines), by=9)], header=FALSE)[,2]
 v1
 #[1] 25.77898 17.95230 20.06718
```

Another option would be using `awk` command on the linux terminal after changing the working directory as the one where the input data file is found.  We read every 9th line starting from the 7th, get the 2nd column (`$2`), and create a new file ('file1.txt') with the output

```
 awk 'NR%9==7 {print $2}' file.txt > file1.txt
```

The contents of 'file1.txt'

```
  awk '{print}' file1.txt
  #25.7789822728439
  #17.9522993970202
  #20.0671762933887
```